# backbone js view event binding only to views elements

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views, event-binding

Hi I'm learning backbone and I am having trouble with binding events to views.  My problem is that I have a view constructor that when called, binds all views to a button press event that is only part of one view. I would like the button press event to be bound to only the 1 view that contains the button.

http://jsbin.com/tunazatu/6/edit?js,console,output

1. click on all of the view buttons
2. then click back to view 1
3. click the red button (all view's models console.log their names)

So I've looked at the code from this post [mutliple event firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20988342/backbone-bind-event-happen-multiple-times) which shows that you can have multiple views that have the same el thru tagName but map events only to their html elements.  This is also what is done in the localtodos example from Jérôme Gravel-Niquet

I have also tried not declaring el /tunazatu/7/edit?js,console,output but then it seems like no event gets bound.

```
    var AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName:"div",  //tagName defined
    getName:function(){
      console.log(this.model.get('name'));
    },
    initialize:function(options){
      this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', this.render);
      var temp_mapper = {appView1:'#route1',appView2:'#route2',appView3:'#route3'};
      var m_name = this.model.get('name');
      this.template = _.template($(temp_mapper[m_name]).html());  //choose the correct template
    },
    render:function(){
      var temp = this.template(this.model.toJSON()); //populate the template with model data
      var newElement = this.$el.html(temp);  //put it in the view's tagName
      $('#content').html(newElement);
    },
    events:{
      "click button":"log"
    },
    log:function(){
      this.getName();
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that your `AppView` really looks like this:

```
var AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: "#content",
    //...
```

Every time you create a new `AppView`, you bind another event delegator to `#content` but you never remove those delegations. If you create three `AppView`s, you end up with three views listening to `click button` inside `#content`.

I would recommend two things:

1. Avoid trying to re-use views, create and destroy them (via [`View#remove`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-remove)) as needed. Views should be lightweight enough that putting them together and tearing them down should be cheap.
2. Don't bind multiple views to the same `el`. Instead, let each view create its own `el` and then let the caller put that `el` *inside* some container.

If you do both of those things then your problem will go away. Your `AppView` would look more like this:

```
var AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
  render: function() {
    this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
    return this; // Common practise, you'll see why shortly.
  },
  // As you already have things...
});
```

Then your router methods would look more like this:

```
view1: function() {
  if(this.appView)
      this.appView.remove();
  this.appView = this.createView('appView1');
  $('#content').html(this.appView.render().el);
  // that `return this` is handy ----------^^
},
```

If you must stick with your current approach then you'll have to call [`undelegateEvents`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-undelegateEvents) on the current `AppView` before you render another one and [`delegateEvents`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-delegateEvents) on the new `AppView` after you render it.

But really, don't be afraid to destroy views that you don't need right at this moment: destroy any view that you don't need on the page right now and create new instances when you need them. There are cases where you don't want to destroy your views but you can usually avoid it.

Comment: thanks for the reply that really helped me
a follow up question: when you said this _Don't bind multiple views to the same el. Instead, let each view create its own el and then let the caller put that el inside some container._ If you have to attach jquery events, what is the best way to do that from the caller's scope

Comment: Generally you shouldn't be manually binding jQuery events, you can almost always use the `events` object in the appropriate view instead. Keep in mind that `delegateEvents` uses the delegation form of jQuery's `on` so elements don't have to exist when the `el` is created; if you have to deal with non-bubbling events then you can use `this.$(...)` to find the elements to bind to and then unbind in a `View#remove` override.